# GIMP/Imagemagick: Breaking single images into multiple images

Tags: gimp, imagemagick, image-processing

I have pulled the image files from [this](https://gregg.angelfishy.net) Gregg Shorthand resource site with the intent of using the shorthand figures in Anki flashcards to complement my study of the system. You will note that the images (a handful of which can be seen [here](https://gregg.angelfishy.net/anunit11.shtml), for example) vary in size and proportion, but generally follow the pattern of being dark stroke on a white background, and having words paired with the shorthand figures that represent them.

There are a few hundred such images represent thousands of figures in total, so I'm looking for a way to programmatically slice these single images into individual figures. I do not care whether or not the words alongside them are preserved. I have both GIMP and Imagemagick available.